# VS 2010 WPF Google API Calender V3 Insert Events

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, google-calendar-api

I have created a WPF Application in VS 2010 and user the Google API V3

I am facing the issue in

```
var CalEvt = mCalendarService.Events.Insert(new Event()
                    {
           Description = item.Body.Substring(0, Math.Min(30, item.Body.Length)),
           Start = new EventDateTime { DateTime = item.DueDateStart.ToString("o") },
           End = new EventDateTime { DateTime = item.DueDateEnd.ToString("o") },
           ETag = item.ExtractItemID.ToString(),
           Reminders = new Event.RemindersData() { Overrides = l, UseDefault = false }
           }, item.ExtractItemID.ToString()).Execute();
```

I am getting exception specified value is not in valid quoted string.

For Authentication I have used the below code
    var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(provider, GetAuthorization);

```
        BaseClientService.Initializer initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer();
        initializer.Authenticator = auth;
        mCalendarService = new Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.CalendarService(initializer);
```